# PHP Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, undefined, offset

I am having troubles with this part

```
    ";

    $primary_image = dbSelect($db, $query);
    $project->primary_image = $primary_image[0];

    }
```

of this code

```
<?php

require_once('includes/config.php');

    enter code here

require_once('includes/lib.php');

$db = dbConnect();

$query = "SELECT projects.* FROM projects ORDER BY rank ASC";
$projects = dbSelect($db, $query);

foreach($projects as $project) {
    $query = "
        SELECT media.* FROM media
        WHERE media.project_id = '$project->id'
        AND media.primary = '1'
    ";

    $primary_image = dbSelect($db, $query);
    $project->primary_image = $primary_image[0];

    }

dbClose($db);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Missy Skae's Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<?

foreach($projects as $project) {
    ?>
    <div class="project">
        <h2><?=$project->date;?></h2>
        <h1><a href="project.php?id=<?=$project->id;?>"><?=$project->title;?></a></h1>
        <div class="primary-image">
            <a href="project.php?id=<?=$project->id;?>"><img src="media/<?=$project->primary_image->filename;?>"></a>
        </div>
        <h2><?=$project->tag1;?></h2>
        <h1><?=$project->description;?></h1>
    </div>
    <?
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

the error being Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try a `print_r($primary_image);` and see what returns there. There is no `$primary_image[0]` so see what is there.

Comment: That would suggest that your query is returning no rows. Try `var_dump($primary_image);`.

Comment: Or you have an associative array, either way, `var_dump` should answer your question.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/year_3/Site_2/portfolio/index.php on line 19
array(0) { }

Comment: Print your sql query and test it directly in your dbms query editor, does it return values there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notice should give you a line number, Can you provide it.

In your query, You should update this line:

```
    WHERE media.project_id = '$project->id'
```

to read

```
    WHERE media.project_id = '{$project->id}'
```

I beleive it would cause an error.

It's difficult to pinpoint the error without knowing what line this is happening on or whats in the other included files. It's more than likely on this line..

```
$project->primary_image = $primary_image[0];
```

You could test it by using a var_dump on $primary_image, like so

```
$primary_image = dbSelect($db, $query);
var_dump($primary_image);
$project->primary_image = $primary_image[0];
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/year_3/Site_2/portfolio/index.php on line 20
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#16 (8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["project_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["primary"]=> string(1) "1" ["rank"]=> string(1) "1" ["filename"]=> string(11) "image_1.jpg" ["mediatype"]=> string(5) "image" ["imagedescription"]=> string(9) "1. Circle" ["imagenumber"]=> string(2) "1." } } array(0) { }

Comment: That actually looks like its returning an array, with the result as the first index. try replacing $primary_image[0] with reset($primary_image).

Really you should be adding some error checking to make sure a result has been returned, check the count of the result first with count($primary_image), if it's greater than 0, or even better if its just one then your fine, if not throw an error.

Comment: I have added data to my database and that seems to have done the trick...is that logical?

Comment: yes, kind of. maybe the indexes have changed. the result was returning an array and the only element of the array did actually have an index of 1, So that's confusing. I would make sure you have at least one row returned, check the count before you try to use the result.

Comment: I am not a star at coding, so I will just take it for granted haha. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: well I would still recommend checking the count beforehand. Also using reset() like reset($primary_image) gets the first element of the array regardless of its index. Good luck with the project anyway. It would be worthwhile closing / answering the question so that others don't try to answer it again.

Answer (score 0):

Just test if this offset exists,

```
$project->primary_image = isset($primary_image[0]) ? $primary_image[0] : NULL; // or whatever instead of NULL, you can choose any default value, eg. 'no_image.png'
```